# Ошибка при сохранении данных в БД

Tags: c#, sql-server

При сохранении данных в БД возникает ошибка:

> Существует назначенный этой команде Command открытый DataReader,
>   который требуется предварительно закрыть

Удаление работает отлично, все удаляется, но при новом добавлении данных возникает ошибка. В коде отметил строку где возникает ошибка. В чем причина и как её исправить?

```
public bool UpdateSettings(Guid settingsId, List<UsersModel> usersModel)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        try
        {
            using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = "DELETE FROM UsersSettings WHERE SettingsId = @SettingsId";
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SettingsId", settingsId);
                command.ExecuteReader();
            }

            foreach (var userModel in usersModel)
            {
                using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    command.CommandText = @"INSERT UsersSettings(SettingsId, SettingsValue, IsEnabled)
                                            VALUES (@SettingsId, @SettingsValue, 1)";
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SettingsId", settingsId);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SettingsValue", userModel.SettingsValue);
                    command.ExecuteReader();  // Ошибка возникает в данной строке
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            _log.LogError("Не удалось сохранить настройки.", exception);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reader, который возвращает ExecuteReader, нужно вручную закрывать. Если не используете результат запроса, вызывайте ExecuteNonQuery.

Comment: Либо, как вариант 2 если очень хочется ридер, ридер нужно тоже обвернуть в `using()`

Comment: точно, как то упустил этот момент, спасибо большое)